# Wrong answer when using minimize in scipy

Tags: optimization, scipy

I recently applied for a job and was asked to maximize `f(x,y)= x * y` with a constraints: 1. `x > 0`; 2. `y > 0`; and 3. `x + 2y >= 500`.  At the time I gave the wrong answer but a good guess.  Using pencil and paper with lagrange multipliers I got x=333.4 and y =166.7.  Then I tried using scipy.  Scipy does not have a maximize function, only minimize. So, I changed the cost function to f(x, y) = -x * y and tried minimize.  I don't get the right answer, I get x=250.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is the code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# MAX(a*b) : a+2b <= 500, a>0, b>0
# let x = [a, b]

# ref https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/f19-06623/13-constrained-optimization.html


def objective(x):
    a, b = x
    return -a * b


def c1(x):
    a, b = x
    return -(a + 2 * b - 500)


def c2(x):
    # Positivity constraint
    return x[0]


def c3(x):
    # Positivity constraint
    return x[1]


a = 0.1
x0 = (a, 0.5 * (500 - a))

cons = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': f} for f in (c1, c2, c3)]
sol = minimize(objective, x0, constraints=cons)

print(sol)

a, b = sol['x']
print(f"{a * b} is a * b from the solution.")
print(f"Is a + 2b = {a + 2 * b} <= 500")

a_check = 500 - 2 * b
print(f"{a_check} is a calculated from solution value for b and should be {a}.")
```

Comment: Assuming you meant `x + 2y <= 500` (which is what you implemented in the code), `(x, y) = (250, 125)` is the correct answer.  Why do you think this is not the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is right.  Thank you.  I had a problem with my pencil and paper lagrange method solution. Turns out I had that wrong.  Thank you.

M.